Use np.where to create a list with same number of elements, but different content
I have a pandas dataframe where a value sometimes gets NA. I want to fill this column with a list of strings with the same length as another column:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["one", "two"],
                   "b": ["three", "four"],
                   "c": [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
                   "d": [[5, 6], np.nan]})




a
b
c
d




one
three
[1, 2]
[5, 6]


two
four
[3, 4]
NaN



and I want this to become



a
b
c
d




one
three
[1, 2]
[5, 6]


two
four
[3, 4]
[no_value, no_value]



I tried
df["d"] = np.where(df.d.isna(),
                   ['no_value' for element in df.c],
                   df.d)

and
df["d"] = np.where(df.d.isna(),
                   ['no_value'] * len(df.c),
                   df.d)

but both does not work. Anyone has an idea?
SOLUTION:
I adjusted PaulS answer a little to:
df[‘d‘] = np.where(df.d.isna(), 
                   pd.Series([['no_value'] * len(lst) for lst in df.c]), 
                   df.d))


What errors do you get?  What's the where result withiut the column assifnment?

IIRC there was no error, but the field just stayed NaN. I’ll double check tomorrow.

A possible solution consists in using np.where.
df.assign(d = np.where(
    df['d'].isna(), 
    pd.Series([['no_value'] * len(lst) for lst in df['c']]), 
    df['d']))


Another possible solution, which uses:

apply on df, iterating through each row with a lambda function that checks whether the value in column d is NaN.

If the condition is met, the function generates a new list filled with the string 'no_value' repeated to match the length of the list in column c.

If x['d'] does not meet these conditions, the original value in x['d'] is retained.


df['d'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ['no_value'] * len(x['c']) 
    if (x['d'] is np.nan) else x['d'], axis=1)


Output:
     a      b       c                     d
0  one  three  [1, 2]                [5, 6]
1  two   four  [3, 4]  [no_value, no_value]


Wow, that looks pretty solid. Gonna try that out tomorrow :). Thanks.

To use where we have to construct a correct nan containing array, one that is like df.d, with object dtype lists.
In [317]: df1=df.copy();df1
Out[317]: 
     a      b       c       d
0  one  three  [1, 2]  [5, 6]
1  two   four  [3, 4]     NaN

To have full control start with an empty object dtype array, and fill it.
In [318]: x=np.empty(len(df.c), object)    
In [319]: x[:] = [[np.nan]*len(element) for element in df.c]; x
Out[319]: array([list([nan, nan]), list([nan, nan])], dtype=object)

This 2-step wouldn't be needed if the df.c lists varied in length.  Now where can use the [False, True] condition to choose between elements of the 2 object dtype arrays.
In [320]: df1.d = np.where(df.d.isna(), x, df.d)

In [321]: df1
Out[321]: 
     a      b       c           d
0  one  three  [1, 2]      [5, 6]
1  two   four  [3, 4]  [nan, nan]


In [326]: x = [[np.nan]*len(element) for element in df.c]; x
Out[326]: [[nan, nan], [nan, nan]]

won't do because it's a (2,2) shape, and where will have problems 'broadcasting' that with the other terms ((2,) Series).
Or you could initialize x as
x = df.c.copy()

